# Do companies register DNS sub-domains or handle it themselves?

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, windows-server

If my university `uno.edu` has all public IP addresses and it wants to add a department as a DNS subdomain i.e.  `cs.uno.edu`

Will it typically handle the subdomain itself on it's local on campus DNS servers?
Or will it register that subdomain with a registrar?

Also, will windows server handle remote internet DNS requests?

I'm asking because I'm trying to figure out how powerful windows server DNS capabilities are.

Comment: It depends whether university can manage their own dns server. If they have their own dns server they can manage their own dub domains perfectly. Also Windows is not that much suitable when you have your own dns server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*uno.edu/computer-science* is not a subdomain, but a URL. A subdomain would be **computer-science.uno.edu**.

The DNS server of the top-level-domain *edu* will reference to the DNS server of your university (*uno.edu*) and that one manages all subdomains on an local DNS server (like the aforementioned computer-science.uno.edu for instance). However, it's also possible that your university does not host an own DNS server if they don't need to manage subdomains.

And yes, Windows Server can certainly handle remote requests.